# How to fix Neo4j browser which is showing only grey for different labels?

Tags: neo4j

I ran (multiple times) the below query on an empty database which only shows Grey colour for all nodes inspite of them having different labels.

```
CREATE (js: Jobseeker {name:'Bala'}) 
CREATE (c: Company {name:'Google'}) 
CREATE (c1: Company {name: 'Yahoo'}) 
CREATE (s: Skill {name:'Ruby'}) 
CREATE (js)-[:CAN_USE]->(s) 
CREATE (c)-[:USES]->(s) 
CREATE (js)-[:WORKED]->(c1) 
CREATE (js)-[:WORKS_IN]->(c) 
RETURN js, c, c1, s;
```

If I run CREATE separately (i.e. for each node category) they come up in different colours as expected.  Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reset the style with this command in the browser:

```
:style reset
```

Furthermore you can change the styles by creating a [Graph Style Sheet](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/#_styling_neo4j_browser_visualization) or updating the styles directly in the browser:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome you can reset style settings using F12 and navigate to Resources and Local Storage and delete the `neo4j.grass` entry. On other browser the same procedure should help as well.